# How to keep the last status of user in a flow and make it plug-able?

Tags: python, node.js, database, architecture

I want to build a system that has around 100 states for a single user. It means it is an ecosystem in which users can play around in the different sections of the app on different platforms (Web, Mobile, and Desktop).
I will split the states that are sequential (like registration) and another group that is not sequential and the user can choose which one he wants to select but after selection, each of them has a sequential flow (like buy, sell a good).
I know a legacy way that I can hold the status of the user in a field and anytime based on that field system can lead the user for the next steps even the user sign out from the system and wants to come back another time.
But I want to know is this way the best practice?
I know this way can make the system too complicated and later on adding even 1 step or another flow is a pain.
Any idea I would appreciate to have that helps me to design the ecosystem.
Please consider that the app itself is not important because it can be used in many use cases.